# C function split array into chunks

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I have an array of `bytes` aka `unsigned char` called `content`. I want to split my `content` array into 2 new arrays in a separate function. This function should also determine the size for each of the 2 chunks and allocate memory for them. Also, I want to be able to use both the new arrays and their sizes outside of the function. My implementation is giving me `segmentation fault` and I must be doing something with pointers wrong.

Main function

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    byte *content = NULL;
    size_t size_content;

    byte *param = NULL;
    size_t size_param;

    byte *data = NULL;
    size_t size_data;

    // This works fine!
    size_content = load_file_to_memory(argv[1], "rb", &content);

    // split content
    split_content(content, &param, &data,
            size_content, &size_param, &size_data);

    // SEGMENTATION ERROR
    putchar(param[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Split Content Function:

```
    void split_content(byte *content, byte **param, byte **data,
            size_t size_content, size_t *size_param, size_t *size_data) {
    *size_param = get_number_of_param_bytes(content);
    *size_data = size_content - *size_param;

    *param = malloc((*size_param) * sizeof(byte));
    *data = malloc ((*size_data) * sizeof(byte));

    for(size_t i=0; i<*size_param; i++) {
        *param[i] = content[i];
    }

    for(size_t i=*size_param; i<size_content; i++) {
        *data[i-*size_param] = content[i];
    }
}
```

Get number of param bytes function:

```
    size_t get_number_of_param_bytes(byte *content) {
    size_t num_whites = 0;
    size_t byte_index = 0;
    do {
        byte b = content[byte_index];
        if(isspace(b)) {
            num_whites += 1;
        }
        byte_index += 1;
    } while (num_whites < N_WS);
    return byte_index;
}
```

Load file to memory:

```
    size_t load_file_to_memory(const char *filename, const char *mode, byte **buffer) {
    size_t size = 0;

    FILE *file = fopen(filename, mode);
    if (file == NULL) {
        *buffer = NULL;
        printf("Unable to open file! Terminating...\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    size = get_file_size(file);
    *buffer = malloc(size * sizeof(byte));

    if (fread(*buffer, sizeof(byte), size, file) != size) {
        printf("Error loading file into memory! Terminating...\n");
        free(*buffer);
        exit(-1);
    }

    fclose(file);
    return size;
}
```

It must be something with the pointers that I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger, or e.g. valgrind?

Comment: Why do you need to pass a pointer to a pointer for the param and data fields?  It should be enough to simply have a single pointer.  The segmentation fault is most likely happening in the for loops when you try to copy.  The array index for param is going to be completed prior to the dereferencing *.  With your current code, you might try (*param)[i] instead of *param[i].

Comment: I dont know, when I tried with single pointer I just got segmentation fault. Is the double pointer needed in the load_file_to_memory() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of precedence rules, `*param[i]` means `*(param[i])`, but you actually want `(*param)[i]`.

Likewise, `*data[i-*size_param]` means `*(data[i-*size_param])` but you want `(*data)[i-*size_param]`.

Add the extra brackets around `*param` and `*data`.

Comment: That's nice that you stole what I had said in a comment above!